# Scala Gson Type Adapter not Being Called on List[Enumeration]

Tags: scala, gson

In Scala I have:

```
object CameraIds extends Enumeration {
  type CameraIds = Value
  val LB, LF, FC, RF, RB, L, F, R, B = Value

  def fromString(s: String): Option[Value] = values.find(
    _.toString.toLowerCase() == s.toLowerCase())
}

case class Filter(validCameraIds: List[CameraIds])
```

Then I have a type adapter for this to be used with converting Json to a Filter.

```
def getListOfCameraIdsTypeAdapter: TypeAdapter[List[CameraIds]] = {
  new TypeAdapter[List[CameraIds]] {
    override def write(out: JsonWriter, value: List[CameraIds]):
      Unit = {
      val gson: Gson = new Gson()
      val array: JsonWriter = out.beginArray()
      value.foreach(camId => array.value(camId.toString))
      out.endArray()
    }

    override def read(in: JsonReader): List[CameraIds] = {
      val cameraIds: mutable.Builder[Option[CameraIds], 
        List[Option[CameraIds]]] = List.newBuilder[Option[CameraIds]]
        in.beginArray()
        while (in.hasNext) {
          val nextCamId = in.nextString()
          cameraIds += CameraIds.fromString(nextCamId)
        }
        in.endArray()
        cameraIdsRet.map(_.get)
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I use Gson to deserialize the following:

```
{
  "cameraIds": ["FC", "LB", "RF"]
}
```

Using the following:

```
val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken[List[CameraIds]]() {}.getType,
    getListOfCameraIdsTypeAdapter)
  .create()
val reader: JsonReader = new JsonReader(
  new FileReader(configFilePath.toString));
gson.fromJson(reader, classOf[Filter]);
```

However the type adapter's `read` method is never called and `Filter`'s `validCameraIds` is always `null`.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the case class variable name of `validCameraIds` differs from the name in the Json string key of `"cameraIds"`. Apparently Gson looks at the case class variable names before parsing.